# Where can I take a COVID-19 antigenic test in Paris?

Tags: france, covid-19, paris

I'm travelling to Paris next week, and before we return to Germany, one of my fellow travellers, who isn't vaccinated, will have to take an antigenic test. Where in Paris can one take such a test on a Saturday or very early on Sunday? Is there a website that lists testing facilities (and their opening hours and prices)?

Comment: Remember that in France there are a lot of things you can’t currently do if you are not vaccinated or recently tested, including flying, taking long distance trains and buses, entering restaurants, bars, museums, etc. So unless your stay is short and your friend gets tested just before leaving, they will probably need to get tested earlier than just before leaving.

Comment: @jcaron My friend has to get tested to enter France, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: Please stay 'nice'. Not everybody can take the vaccination, due to health reasons among other things. And even if they get the jab now, it will take weeks before they can travel with it, so the test will stay needed.

Answer (score 8):

Ups, found it myself:

https://www.sante.fr/cf/centres-depistage-covid.html

Here you find that list.

Answer (score 5):

In practice, literally everywhere. Most pharmarcies provide that service and there are many pharmacies in Paris. When going through  Paris, you will see many tents or so-called “[barnums](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnum_(tente))” on the sidewalk next to pharmacies or official buildings, and sometimes containers too. Those are all testing sites but even pharmacies that do not have a tent typically offer tests inside.

You will also come across surprisingly many medical labs (*laboratoire d'analyses* or *laboratoire biomédical*) as those were already pretty common in France (you would go there for many exams rather then rely on a GP practice or hospitals as many other countries do). As an example, there are 8 within 1 km of my location in the North-West of Paris! By now, they should all offer Covid-19 testing (especially PCR tests).

Almost all of these testing sites should be open on Saturday. For Sunday testing or PCR tests (or outside of Paris, obviously), you may want to look up the list, other than that you would be hard pressed to walk more than a couple of blocks without stumbling on a testing facility and the list is too long to be useful.

Price is regulated and should be the same everywhere (€25, €30 on Sunday, about €40+ if you go to a GP as they charge you for a medical consultation and not merely a test). You get a printout in French and English and an EU digital covid certificate on the spot (you have to provide a phone number and you will get a SMS with a link in it as soon as the result of the test is registered in the [SI-DEP](https://www.ameli.fr/pharmacien/actualites/depistage-de-la-covid-19-saisie-dans-si-dep-des-tests-antigeniques)).

Do note that tests were free of charge for French residents until very recently but that has now changed. If the new rules further increase the vaccination rate and reduce the demand for tests, it's possible some pharmacies will get out of this business or at least get rid of their tents (it does cost quite a bit of money to have someone sit outside just for this if demand is not there).